# Initializing IBM WebSphere MQ in Java

Tags: java, ibm-mq, mq

I am very new to **IBM WebSphere MQ**.

I have a new mission to connect remote Queue in Java using MQ. I have IBM WebSphere MQ client installed in my local, and I have two information which are **Queue Manager Name** and **Queue Name**

Can anyone walk me through the steps to connect remote queue in java code? Or could you provide me any instruction/sample code that I can use as reference?

Appreciate for your help

Comment: Please take a look at Java samples shipped with MQ Client. If you are on Windows, the samples can be found in <MQ install folder>\tools\jms\samples and <MQ install folder>\tools\wmqjava\samples folder.

Comment: Would recommend that you focus on the JMS api; this is the open standard API and provides good connectivity to MQ

Answer (score 1):

> Can anyone walk me through the steps to connect remote queue in java
>   code?

Sure.  Have a look at [IBM WebSphere Developer Technical Journal: Running a standalone Java application on WebSphere MQ V6.0](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/websphere/techjournal/0610_woolf/0610_woolf.html).  Although this was written for MQ v6.0, the code still works on later versions of MQ. The article includes downloadable code and extensive explanations of how it works.

> Or could you provide me any instruction/sample code that I can use as
>   reference?

As opposed to the code IBM provides? ;-) As Shashi notes in the comments, have a look in the `<MQ install folder>\tools\jms\samples` and `<MQ install folder>\tools\wmqjava\samples` folders if you are on Windows. If you are on *NIX then look under `<MQ install folder>/samp`.

Of course, these are not the only samples available.  Roger over at Capitalware has amassed one of the largest (if not *the* largest) collections of source code samples and an index of 3rd party products for MQ anywhere.  Within that vast trove, you want to check out the [Java Applications](http://www.capitalware.com/java.html) category in the Downloads section.